# Error code 1, -110 in media player android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, beagleboard

I got the MediaPlayer error code as (1,-110)  on BeagleBoard Hardware running ICS.The code runs fine on android tablets with ICS but I get a dialog box as "Sorry,this video cannot be played" error on BeagleBoard only.Any suggestions.

Comment: May be `BeagleBoard` does not have the required codec..

Comment: I have a playlist of video files.It plays fine the very first time and gives the error on playing second time or randomly sometimes.So I dnt think its a codec problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a time out error from the MediaPlayer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT

Also, it may happen with an issue with Samsung firmware on Android 4.1.2, I've seen it in Galaxy S2 mini and Galaxy S3. Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378273/3032209
You could solve it if you play the file it with another library, which will have the adequate codecs, like [aacdecoder-android](https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/)

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is too late to your question and I think you were able to fix this problem by now, but if not and for those people who are struggling with the Media Player Error (1, -110) (like I did the whole day today, Android HTC Desire X Jelly Bean 4.1.1), maybe this is the solution for you:

Just reboot your android (or close all the apps, which are using the Media Player).

In my case it was not a programming error, I just had to many apps open using the Media Player Instance, which led to that time out and I could not use it anymore.

Comment: It was resolved.We had to increase the timestamp of image buffering into the android source code.