# Why does MediaPlayer not prepare?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using `MediaPlayer` to load an mp3 file and play it online. I am using this code:

```java
try{
    Log.i("tag1", "try");
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(activity.this, Uri.parse("link"));
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.i("tag2", "" + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        }
    });
    } catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Most of the times nothing is prepared, so I have the `log.i` results as below:

`tag1 = try`

`tag2` is never executed

If, sometimes only, `mediaPlayer` is prepared, I get these logs:

`tag1 = try`

`tag2 = 0` _ which is neither acceptable nor usable

Also, when I call `mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener`, I get errors `1,-1004` or `1,-2147483648`. Additionally, `mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener` gives nothing; I think it's never called...

**What could be the problem?**

It is not unnecessary to mention that in the **log folder of the server's file manager**, I found this: `"stagefright/1.2 (Linux; Android 4.4.4)"`. I think this could help to solve the problem. *Also, related to this, can the problem be caused by PHP extensions? if yes, activating which extension solves this issue?*

---

***Any help is really appreciated.***

Comment: what do you expect with such `Uri`: `Uri.parse("link")`? what actually to you want to play?

Comment: @pskink I need to play an mp3, online. like soundcloud, but in the app . . .

Comment: @pskink yeah, the `link` is some path toward server host, where the mp3 file is located . . .

Comment: tried `setOnErrorListener`? if so, what are `int what` and `int extra` in `onError` callback? also check `setOnInfoListener` too

Comment: @pskink my friend; there's nothing on onInfo. however, onError returns `1,-1004` or `1,-2147483648`.

Comment: so check in the official documentation what `-1004` error means

Comment: @pskink I did not find any details for such an error

Comment: Call `setOnPreparedListener` *before* calling `prepareAsync`.

Comment: I'm sure you've seen this, but in case not: Here is a very helpful flowchart of the MediaPlayer state machine. If you divert from this, you gonna run into problems: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/mediaplayer-110716092828-phpapp02/95/android-media-player-9-728.jpg?cb=1310809360

Comment: Dear @muetzenflo, Thanks! I obey those steps. The problem is the `onPrepare` does not prepare or prepares incompletely... so the media is not playable or, at least, the `getDuration` returns 0.

Comment: Sometimes the MediaPlayer isnt able to play files of certain sizes or formats, depending on what device you actually use (had that problem before). You mentioned Soundcloud and as far as I know, many of the files there are very large, like a few hours. Have you tried using different files to maybe narrow down the possible problems?

Comment: @selbie, Although I tried your precious suggestion, I still think you are kind of kidding. :) Thanks so much

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci I really appreciate you very help. I believe the rumors about `mediaPlayer`'s inherent lacks are not completely true except its loading duration which is more than ExoPlayer . . . Since It worked well for me and this issue happend suddenly from nowhere . ..

Comment: Have you tried downloading the file first and then using it instead of straight out streaming it? Also, have you tried other files with maybe different codecs?

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci, I did the latter. The first one, which I had in mind too, does not fit my case . . .

Comment: You should still try it though, just to narrow the room for error to make it easier to pinpoint the actual problem. Because, If downloading it beforehand makes it work, then you know the problem lies within the streaming. If it doesn't help, you know its either your implementation or the file. Always make your problems as small as possible

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci, The trouble is with STREAMING. I tried local files . . .

Comment: I wasn't kidding.   I have an app in the store that uses MediaPlayer.  Feel free to visit [the code here](https://github.com/jselbie/wrekonline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/selbie/wrek/MediaPlayerPresenter.java):

Comment: @selbie, good job. But I don't think "Calling `setOnPreparedListener` before calling `prepareAsync`" can be a logical solution. However I tried it. thanks,,,

Comment: Just in case `prepareAsync` completes before your code had a chance to set a callback.

Comment: @selbie, It just worked well in the existing order of codes. this issue was a sudden stuff. Also `setOnPreparedListener` is a listener; just acts when `prepareAsync` is prepared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I thank all my friends who put their most effort to answer this problem of mine, but none of them solved the main issue.

How I came to find a way to get rid of this situation:

I tried another Host for my files and it worked. So I decided to move all my data and databases to another Host.

Answer (score 2):

You have a [MEDIA_ERROR_IO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_IO). As the documentation says it's for File or network related operation errors.

In most cases the problem is in the implementation of the MediaPlayer class or maybe in android 4 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672568/mediaplayer-error-1-1004-aka-media-error-io-trying-to-stream-music-on-samsun)

I would recommend you [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), instead.

Comment: Thanks my friend! I'm trying several suggestions; among them, ExoPlayer...

Comment: Could you, please, introduce a suitable tutorial source for a ExoPlayer? I just need a simple one for a mp3 player... I need it to be short and to the point. I thank you so much . . .

Comment: sure, there's no better place than google codelabs itself, you can start from here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Comment: thanks! I think I should change my host provider to give a try to another service, no solution works . . .

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `mediaPlayer.start()` in your `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()`. See attached kotlin code for an extending class with example http request

Error `1004`: Source not found (f.e. wrong path or no stream at url)

Error `2147483648`: Media format not supported at your device

Another mention: keeping references for audiofiles on device system needs **persistable uri permission**

Here's stripped down code for starting a radio stream in kotlin with OkHttp

```
class MyPlayer: MediaPlayer(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

  fun playStream() {
    try {
        val uri = Uri.parse( [URL] )

        //check if url valid
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url( [URL] ).build()
        val newCall = client.newCall(request).execute()
        if (newCall.code() != 200) {
            //handle error for stream, stream not broadcasting
            return
        }

        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
        headers.put("User-Agent", " [SOME AGENT] ")
        setDataSource(context, uri, headers)

        prepareAsync()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        L.e("Url Parsing failed for ${e.message}")
        setInternalState(State.Error, StreamErrorMapping.ShoutCastError)
    }
  }
}

override fun onPrepared(player: MediaPlayer) {
    player.start()  //<-- this call is missing in your code
}
```

By the way, like **Ezaldeenn sahb** already mentioned, I would also recommend using `ExoPlayer`, since it's way more faster than `MediaPlayer`! In my projects buffering went down from 2-4seconds (MediaPlayer) to 200ms (Exoplayer). Happy coding

Comment: I Thank you for you help. How is it possible to `start` a `mediaPlayer` while the `onPrepare` does not response or responds odd? I have used `.start()` in my code, where the play button takes action, which induces the issue. However, here, I've just brought the `logi` of my codes to show the errors.

Comment: Could you, please, introduce a suitable tutorial source for a ExoPlayer? I just need a simple one for a mp3 player...

Comment: This is another question, but here s all you need: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: You cannot call `start()` if `onPrepared()` wasn't called. If onPrepared isn't called, something is wrong with your media source or format

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to change my host . . . ,  plenty of stuff to do...

Answer (score 1):

It seems your problem is because of using `http` links instead of `https`. Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your manifest application tag like so:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
      ...

</application>
```

Also, don't forget to use `internet` permission.